# Pyodbc, how to get results from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I have a stored procedure I have to work with. From SQL developer is gives results that look like a table. But when I try to get the results with Pyodbc, I only get:

> Error: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.

I think it's how the results are being produced maybe, because it's using select. I'm not sure how to get the output. I've tried a few other ideas from guides and SO questions, but I've had no luck.

The SP looks like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE schema.spname
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @NewLogID BIGINT
        DECLARE @recs INT = 0
        DECLARE @Process VARCHAR(200) = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)

        -- Log the Process
        EXEC anrm.WriteANRMLog @ProcessName = @Process,@ReturnLogID=@NewLogID OUTPUT    
        SELECT receipt_id, order_id, user_id
        FROM tableA
        WHERE A.Qty>0
        AND datesent IS NULL
        
        --EXEC schema.othertable @RecordCount = @recs,@logid= @NewLogID, @ReturnLogID=@NewLogID OUTPUT
        PRINT @Process + ' - Completed'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        EXEC anrm.PrintError
        --EXEC anrm.LogNRMError 
    END CATCH

END
```

And I'm trying to get the results, most recently, like this.

```
try:
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' +
            server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD=' + password)
    cnxn.autocommit = True
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SET NOCOUNT ON; exec schema.spname")

    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row:
        print(str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
        row = cursor.fetchone()

    cursor.close()
    del cursor
    cnxn.close()

except Exception as e:
    print("Error: %s" % e)
```

Comment: `SET NOCOUNT ON;` is redundant in `cursor.execute("SET NOCOUNT ON; exec schema.spname")` because it's already specified as the first statement in your stored procedure. You might want to check `anrm.WriteANRMLog` to make sure it's not doing something silly like `SET NOCOUNT OFF;`.

Comment: WriteANRMLog doesn't have anything that looks troublesome. It also sets nocount on.

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify the SP?  If so, instead of running the select in the SP, have it insert results into a temp table.  Then in python

```
cursor.execute("exec schema.spname")
cursor.execute("select * from #my_temp_table")
cursor.execute("drop table #my_temp_table")
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
# SQL Server format
cursor.execute("exec sp_dosomething(123, 'abc')")

# ODBC format
cursor.execute("{call sp_dosomething(123, 'abc')}")
```

Comment: How does this call the stored procedure?

Comment: Sorry, I got distracted and copied/pasted the wrong thing.